# Dropdown Menu (CSS only) on Click & With Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to make a dropdown menu - in CSS only - that drops down on mouse-click (instead of on mouse-hover) and has a scroll bar, as there will be around 22 options.  What I have so far, is here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yobqsjb2/1/

(I am limited to CSS only, as Javascript, PHP, etc are blocked by the university.  I also cannot use the select or options codes (IE: [select name='menu'] [option value='1']first item[/option]) in the HTML of the page, because the editor keeps stripping them out.  I gather from looking online that the TinyMCE visual editor on WordPress is doing this, but unfortunately, I have no access to change it, so I need to work around the limitation.)

I've grabbed code from other sources to tweak, but I fully admit that I was more on the PC repair side of things a few years ago (career-changed and now migrating the company website in the new field) not a former programmer.  A lot of what I'm seeing that is supposed to fix the problem for other users' code, I don't quite understand what they're doing well enough to apply it here...

I know the "on click" problem is with the a:hover and li:hover (vs a:active / li:active), but when I switch them, the menu goes away when the mouse hits it.  I read that I needed a 'display:block;' somewhere in the code, but based on examples shown, I've put it in each code segment and in all of them... it doesn't seem to want to fix the problem.

In terms of the scroll bar, everything I keep finding is in Javascript or, in a few places saying that it can't be done for IE (ideally, it would work everywhere, or have an IE alternative that wouldn't look funky).

Are either or both of these things possible?  I've figured out how to change the dropdown menu's size, color, borders, etc, just not these two items...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using the `details` tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Comment: This looks promising!  Definitely looking at it later in the day!  Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if this works for you. You should note that the support for the tag is not great. Look here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details. At the moment Firefox and IE (no surprise there) do not support the tag (for desktop) and only Androids support it for mobile

Answer (score 0):

For the `:focus` to work, you'd need a `tabindex` for the element (`li`).

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yobqsjb2/3/

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the tabindex.  I assume I need a 'display:block' somewhere in order to make it stop going back up once the mouseclick event is over?  (That was something I had read, I just didn't know where to put it, because the person wasn't doing the menu using the list functions...)